# How to add fields to a Google Form visible only to specific users

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to add fields to a Google Form which are visible only to specific users (based on their email ID)? Or allow only users whose email IDs fall in a set to fill the fields?

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Google Forms doesn't include a feature to hide questions.

## Explanation

Google Forms could use page navigation to control wich questions will be available for the respondents but it's controlled by multiple choice questions, not by users ID.

## Alternative

Create an specific form for each set of users then send to each of them the corresponding form.

## Remarks

- Later you could merge the answers of all the forms or you could do it dynamically by using arrays to join/merge non-adjacent ranges.
- Different Google Forms could send the answers to different sheets of the same spreadsheets.
- If you decide to use different spreadsheets for each form, you could use IMPORTRANGE() to put in one spreadsheet all the response ranges.

## References

- [Using arrays with Google Sheets - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Answer (score -3):

I have not tried this but I think probably Google Script might help you in this. Find this link to create a google forms programmatically.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.

```
// Create a new form, then add a checkbox question, a multiple choice question,
// a page break, then a date question and a grid of questions.
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?');
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
        item.createChoice('Mustard'),
        item.createChoice('Relish')
    ]);
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
    .setChoiceValues(['Cats','Dogs'])
    .showOtherOption(true);
form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle('Getting to know you');
form.addDateItem()
    .setTitle('When were you born?');
form.addGridItem()
    .setTitle('Rate your interests')
    .setRows(['Cars', 'Computers', 'Celebrities'])
    .setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
```

With Google Script, you can access logged in users email id
with :

```
// Log the email address of the person running the script.
 Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
```

By combining these two functionalities it might be possible to add questions as per users.
I hope this might help you. I'll edit this post with proper code if I get the time.

Comment: I fail to see anything in here that actually solves the OP's problem.